# Convert Header value as row with value

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

```
OwnerID  ShortList DisplayList  QuickStart ShortDateID LongDatetID
-------  --------- -----------  ---------- ----------- -----------
280      10        10           1          4           17
```

output :

```
Key            value
-----------    -----
OwnerID        280              
ShortList      10               
DisplayList    10               
QuickStart     1                
ShortDateID    4                
LongDatetID    17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unpivot

```
SELECT key, value
FROM   
   (SELECT OwnerID, ShortList, DisplayList, QuickStart, ShortDateID, LongDatetID  
   FROM tablename) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (value FOR key IN   
      (OwnerID, ShortList, DisplayList, QuickStart, ShortDateID, LongDatetID)  
)AS unpvt
```

Answer (score 3):

You want `apply` :

```
select tt.[Key], tt.[Value]
from table t cross apply
     ( values ('OwnerID', OwnerID), 
              ('ShortList', ShortList), 
              ('DisplayList', DisplayList),
              ('QuickStart ', QuickStart),
              ('ShortDateID', ShortDateID),
              ('LongDatetID', LongDatetID)
     ) tt ([Key], [Value]);
```